# PyQt5 Окно с прозрачным фоном

Tags: python, gui, pyqt5

Хочу создать окно, которое имеет прозрачный фон внутри.

Перегуглил все варианты. Получаю неизменно черный фон. Вариант с прозрачностью всего окна работает, но не устраивает, так как нужны хорошо видимые рамки окна и пустота внутри.

Пример кода:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Example')
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ex = Example()
    ex.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Попробуйте еще добавить параметр `self.setAttribute(Qt.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)`

Comment: QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground - не сработал . Вин 7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я знаю простой и сложный варианты.

**Простой** через прозрачность всего виджета:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Example')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.6)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Example()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[Сложный](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6ac06d09c80a55a1e4285604f1f5970e07209a09/pyqt__frameless_transparent_window_with_custom_mouse_move.py) [вариант](https://github.com/gil9red/ControlMediaPlayer/blob/f46000702bff76ea6f6eae59a9c3865a8b5f62e6/UWindowControlMediaPlayer.cpp) через удаление рамки окна и отрисовки ее вручную рамки, а еще и логики перемещения окна через клик:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Example')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.press = False
        self.last_pos = QPoint(0, 0)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.press:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self.last_pos)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.press = True

        self.last_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.press = False

    def paintEvent(self, event: QtGui.QPaintEvent):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(Qt.black, 50))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Example()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]